# Terraform version 12 ; 1 aws_instance resource for multiple amis

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Currently utilizing terraform version 12
I do not wish to create 3 different data sources and 3 different instance resources. Is there a way to combine this logic?

```
data "aws_ami" "ids" {
  most_recent = true

  owners = ["1234554321"]

  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["myami1-*", "myami2-*", "myami3-*]
  }
}



 resource "aws_instance" "tes-env" {
  count = number of values in ami_ids list
  ami = each ami in the list
```

Comment: It looks like you already understand how to loop over things with `count` so have you tried using that for your data source too?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR not sure I follow.

Comment: You are already trying to use `count` to loop the `aws_instance.tes-env` resource. Have you tried using that to loop over the `aws_ami.ids` data source? If so do you get an error when you run it? If so can you edit your question to show a [mcve] of that and the full error output?